# ASP.NET Chart 2y axis distinct bar color

Tags: asp.net, charts

I am trying to display 2 y axis values in an ASP.NET Chart.  I can display both of the y axis that I am expecting to see but I can't seem to separate them into different colors.

AxisY Title="Loonies" - I can see them.
AxisY2 Title="Toonies" - I can see them.  The problem is the bars in a column and in a bar graph all show up as the same color.  I have been trying different things and searching google for solutions for hours but I am really stuck.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

ASPX code

```
<asp:Label ID="lblChartType" runat="server" Text="Select Chart Type" Width="130"> </asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlChartType" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Line Graph" Value="Line"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Bar Graph" Value="Bar"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Column" Value="Column"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br /><br />
        <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" Height="275px" Width="500px">
            <Titles><asp:Title Text="Coin Levels % (Last 24 Hours)" /></Titles>
            <Series>
            <asp:Series Name="Series1">
            </asp:Series>
            </Series>
            <ChartAreas>
                <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" >
                    <AxisX Title="Time"> </AxisX>
                    <AxisY Title="Loonies"> </AxisY>
                    <AxisY2 Title="Toonies"></AxisY2>
                </asp:ChartArea>

                </ChartAreas>
        </asp:Chart>
    </center>
```

cs code
    public partial class Charts: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    Shared s = new Shared();

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = (SeriesChartType)Enum.Parse(typeof(SeriesChartType), ddlChartType.SelectedValue);
    GetChartData();
}

private void GetChartData()
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(s.CS))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("hiddenSP", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "hiddenSP";
            Series series = Chart1.Series["Series1"];
            Chart1.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.Time;
            Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "HH:mm";

            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
            series.Points.AddXY(rdr["NEWSTAMP"].ToString().Replace("2016", "").Trim(), rdr["Loonies"].ToString().Replace("%","").Trim());
                series.Points.AddXY(rdr["NEWSTAMP"].ToString().Replace("2016", "").Trim(), rdr["Toonies"].ToString().Replace("%", "").Trim());

            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        s.WebError(ex);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved!

```
    foreach (var item in Chart1.Series[0].Points)

            {
                if (x==0)
                {
                    Color c = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0);
                    item.Color = c;
                    x++;
                }
                else
                {
                    Color c = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 255);
                    item.Color = c;
                    x = 0;
                }
```